ros2 controllers for omni robot
I'm doing a project that use ros2_control on a 3 wheels omni robot. I searched and find https://github.com/mateusmenezes95/omnidirectional_controllers works pretty good. But there is a problem that it's not publish to tf tree so it can't be displayed in rviz2. I'm trying to make it work but it doesn't now.
I want to ask that is there anyone have done this in ros2 or know others source that work on both gazebo and rviz? Thanks for reading.

I'm not aware of one, but:
You could use a separate node to convert the odom topic to tf, like this one
https://index.ros.org/p/odom_to_tf_ros2/
having a quick look in the controller, the tf publisher is prepared but is commented out. Try to uncomment it and see if it works.

i uncomment and add line:
odometry_transform_publisher_->publish(odometry_transform_message_); 
but when launch again gazebo crash after 2 second with error:
exit code -11, cmd 'gzserver -slibgazebo_ros_init.so -slibgazebo_ros_factory.so -slibgazebo_ros_force_system.so']

I can't help you here, but you could have a look into the diff_drive_controller and fix that for the omni_drive. The author for sure will be happy if you open a PR in the repository.
